# SQL Server Group data by week but show the start of the week

Tags: sql-server

I have a query to select customer data and I want to keep an evolution of the number of customers. In week 1 I have 2 new customers so the number is 2. In week 2 I receive 3 new customers, so the number of customers is 5.

I have following query to do this

```
SELECT LAST_UPDATED_WEEK, SUM( NUM_CUSTOMERS ) OVER ( ORDER BY LAST_UPDATED_WEEK ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) AS "Number of customers"
FROM (
  SELECT DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,0,REGISTRATION_DATE),0) AS LAST_UPDATED_WEEK,
         COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ID) AS NUM_CUSTOMERS
  FROM   CUSTOMERS_TABLE
  GROUP BY DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,0,REGISTRATION_DATE),0)) AS T
```

But when I run this query, it doesn't group my data by week. I read about a DATEPART function, but that returns an integer, but I need to have the actual date.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `dd` in `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF` functions with `WEEK`